# How to download all images with the full resolution (i.e. svg) from a single wikipedia article

Tags: sed, grep, wget, images, mediawiki

I was asking myself how to download

- all (.svg) images
- from a single wikipedia article

without doing it manually for each single image. Wikipedia is offering images in different resolutions and several formats using a more complex looking url-scheme

Example url:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-six_Views_of_Mount_Fuji

Comment: Regarding duplicate: my question and the related answer is wikipedia specific and contains informations how to change the default url to get the full-resolution images.

Comment: Closers:  a subset is not a duplicate of a superset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a perfect solution at **dougie.io**'s [Using Wget, Grep, and Sed to Download Public Domain Wallpapers From a Web Page](https://dougie.io/linux/command-line-image-download/).  I'm trying to boil it down to the main steps (to keep it available here as well):

1. Download the HTML page using `wget`:

   ```
   wget https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-six_Views_of_Mount_Fuji \
        -O page.html -O page.html
   ```
2. Extract the image URLs using `grep` and `sed`.  Then extract the URLs from the article and write them to a new file
   *urls.txt*:

   ```
   grep -E "(https?:)?//[^/\s]+/\S+\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)" page.html -o | 
   sed "s/(^https?)?\/\//https\:\/\//g" -r > urls.txt
   ```
3. Download the images using `wget`:

   - **Thumb images**
      If you just need the thumb images you can start that    via:

     ```
     wget -i urls.txt -P downloads/
     ```
   - **Full size images**
     To get the full size images, filter the URLs file (*urls.txt*) to a new file (*urls-new.txt*):

     ```
     sed -E "s/\/thumb//g; s/\/[0-9]+px-.+\.(jpg|png)$//g" urls.txt |
     uniq > urls-new.txt
     ```

     then restart the download:

     ```
     wget -i urls-new.txt -P downloads_full_size/
     ```

Full credit goes to the linked article.